# How to zoom in/out selected elements of MapControl?

Tags: arcobjects, mapcontrol

I have a mapcontrol that includes many elements: text, line.
I used this code to add elements into mapcontrol:

```
 pGraphicsContainer.AddElement(pElement, 0);
```

I can use zoom button to zoom in/out the mapcontrol, but how can I zoom in/out only seleted elements ?

Is there any buttons for this purpose in Arcgis ?

Thanks and regards,

Tai

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT -- For ArcObjects**

You can get the extent of selected graphics using [IGraphicsContainerSelect.SelectionBounds](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0012000005q3000000).  This will return an IEnvelope which you can use to set the extent on your IActiveView.

```
var graphicsSelect = pGraphicsContainer as IGraphicsContainerSelect;
var extent = graphicsSelect.SelectionBounds;
activeView.Extent = extent;
activeView.PartialRefresh();
```

---

On the Edit Menu, there is a Zoom to Selected Elements tool.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Darlene,

But this require a IMxDocument object to get commandBars, but I only have the IMap (FocusMap of my pagelayout control):

myPageLayout.ActiveView.FocusMap

How can I do that ?
PS: I am programming with Arcobjects/ArcgisEngine in C#
Regards,

Tai

Comment: @taibc Updated my answer with some ArcObjects sample code.

Comment: Thank you, I tried but not successfull. And, now, this is not neccessary. Please ignore this